# SQL Server: Update Column with Sum of Other Columns When

Tags: sql-server, database, join

Let's say I have the table structure as shown below. Which SQL script can I use to update the column `Size2` in the table, with the sum of column `Size`, when the animals are equal? Platform is SQL Server.

I want to have a column `Size2` that is the sum of the `Size` when animal names equal each other. I'm struggling to put the script below into an update statement but please see the select statement.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
    Size    nvarchar(50),
    Animals nvarchar(250),
    Part    int,
    Size2   nvarchar(250) 
);
```

| Size | Animals | Part |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Pig | 1 |
| 60 | Tiger | 1 |
| 10 | Tiger | 2 |
| 30 | Pig | 2 |
| 90 | Lion | 1 |
| 20 | Lion | 2 |
| 10 | Lion | 3 |

This is the desired output, I do not have a Size2 column in the table yet.

| Size | Animals | Part | Size2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Pig | 1 | 60 |
| 60 | Tiger | 1 | 70 |
| 10 | Tiger | 2 | 70 |
| 30 | Pig | 2 | 60 |
| 90 | Lion | 1 | 120 |
| 20 | Lion | 2 | 120 |
| 10 | Lion | 3 | 120 |

So far I have:

```sql
SELECT
    Animals,
    SUM(TRY_CONVERT(int, Size))
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    Part IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    Animals
```

Comment: Pl;ease include the desired output afterward, along with your effort to solve the problem yourself. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: We need your `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: It looks like you want a select statement instead of updating a column of the table

Comment: Why are you storing `Size` and `Size2` - which are **obviously** numbers - as `varchar` ?!?

Answer (score 2):

For select statement, you can use PARTITION BY clause

This is select statement

```
SELECT Size, Animals, Part,
SUM(CAST(size as int)) OVER(PARTITION BY Animals) As total_size
FROM table1
WHERE part IS NOT NULL;
```

For update statement

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.size2 = table2.total_size
FROM
    table1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Size, Animals, Part,
    SUM(CAST(size as int)) OVER(PARTITION BY Animals) As total_size
    FROM table1
    WHERE part IS NOT NULL) AS table2
    ON table1.size = table2.size AND
    table1.animals = table2.animals AND
    table1.part = table2.part;
```

Note: UPDATE statement above will only update size2 column where part is not null.

If you want to update all size2 column even though part is null, remove last line(table1.part = table2.part) will do

Answer (score 0):

The desired result can be achieved by following SQL

```
SELECT t.Size, t.Animal, t.Part, t2.AnimalSum
FROM table1 t RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT Animal, Sum(convert(int,Size)) AS AnimalSum
FROM table1
group BY Animal) AS t2 ON t.Animal = t2.Animal
```

so the update can be easily done with an `update` using above query statement.

Answer (score 0):

From your query, you can update with this

```
UPDATE t1
SET 
t1.Size2 = t2.SumSize
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Animals, SUM(TRY_CONVERT(int,Size)) as SumSize
FROM Table1
WHERE Part IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Animals) t2
ON t1.Animals = t2.Animals
```